# Trocar informação entre janelas JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Boa tarde, estou precisando trocar informações entre janelas(scene) diferentes com javaFX, dei uma procurada na net e vi que o mais comum é utilizar comunicação de controllers. 
Meu cenário é o seguinte:
Tela inicial o usuário irá selecionar um estado em uma lista e ao clicar em pesquisar, será aberta outra tela com somente as cidades daquele estado.
Gostaria de um exemplo simples de como trocar essas informações.
Grato.

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho o exemplo, mas se postar o código do que fez talvez consiga te ajudar no que quer.

Imagino que esteja usando FXML, uma maneira que talvez seja mais simples é ao invés de usar o FXMLLoader você poderia instanciar a classe de controle normalmente e depois injetar o controle no FMXL. Assim você poderia usar o construtor da classe pra receber qualquer objeto que deseja.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, se puder adicionar dependências no seu projeto sugiro a lib WindowControllerFx ([link aqui](https://github.com/Andrauss/WindowControllerFx)), ela facilita a inicialização e criação de Stages (janelas) e passagem de parâmetros. Usando a biblioteca ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

Classe de busca:

```
public class FrmLisaCidades extends WindowControllerFx{

    @Override
    public void getFXML(){
      return "/view/tela_busca.fxml";
    }

   private String estado;

   public FrmLisaCidades(String estado){
      super();
      this.estado = estado;
   }

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

      List<Cidade> lista = new cidadeDao().getListaByEstado(estado);
      // Demais funções
   }
}
```

Usando a biblioteca você não precisa se preocupar com FXMLLoader e Stages, além disso pode mostrar a tela diretamente pelo controller:]

```
new FrmListaCidades().show();
```

Dá pra fazer sem a lib? dá, mas é um pouco mais chato:

```
ListaCidadesController controller = meuFxmlLoader.getController();
controller.setEstado(meuEstado); // esse método deve ser criado no controller
```